# access Terraform environment variables within Github Actions

Tags: terraform, environment-variables, github-actions, terraform-provider-aws, cicd

I am creating some resources via Terraform that look like this:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "xx" {
  family                   = "xx"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE", "EC2"]
  container_definitions    = <<TASK_DEFINITION
  [
  {
    "name": "primary",
    "image": "xx",
    "environment": [
      {"PORT": "80", "CONTAINER_CONFIG": var.CONTAINER_CONFIG}}
    ],
  }
]
TASK_DEFINITION
}
```

I do not want to push the hardocded value of a variable (eg CONTAINER_CONFIG) to Github. I don't run terraform apply locally. Terraform is only applied when code is pushed and Github actions run.

How can I use enviornment variables to ensure that the github actions can use the actual variable value without actually pushing the value?

I already created a Github secret and added it to my to Github action .yml file like this:

```
 - name: Terraform apply
        if: steps.plan.outputs.exitcode == 2
        run: terraform apply tfplan
        env:
          TF_VAR_CONTAINER_CONFIG: ${{ secrets.GTM_CONTAINER_CONFIG }}
```

and put this in my vars.tf file:

```
variable "CONTAINER_CONFIG" {
  type      = string
  sensitive = true
}
```

but how do I pass it on to my Terraform file itself?

but with this approach, the `var.CONTAINER_CONFIG` does not work and give me this error:

```
Error: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character 'v' looking for beginning of value
│ 
│   with aws_ecs_task_definition.xx,
│   on gtm.tf line 53, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "xx":
│   53:   container_definitions    = <<TASK_DEFINITION
│   54:   [
│   55:   {
│   56:     "name": "preview",
│   57:     "image": "gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image",
│   58:     "environment": [
│   59:       {"PORT": "80", "CONTAINER_CONFIG": var.CONTAINER_CONFIG}
```

Comment: I think you would need to define the terraform variable first, and then do something like `TF_VAR_container_config=${{ env. CONTAINER_CONFIG }}`. Or alternatively, read through this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html.

Comment: updated the question after trying this @MarkoE

Comment: How about doing `TF_VAR_CONTAINER_CONFIG=${{ secrets.GTM_CONTAINER_CONFIG }} terraform apply tfplan`?

Comment: Nope, that won't work either because the error is still in the .tf file: Error: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character 'v' looking for beginning of value @MarkoE

Comment: It might be the indentation is wrong since you are using heredoc syntax for that. Try to fix it first.

Comment: indentation within the .tf file? i also checked with terraform fmt, don't think that's an issue @MarkoE

Comment: I'm not sure terraform fmt can format heredoc.